# How to unfold a cell with CSV values into a column

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, datatables

all,

Could you please suggest the best way to solve the following task:
I have a table where each cell of a row is filled with comma separated values. Same number of values for a given row.
For each row I need to make a separate table (on demand, on click on a row or separate button with row header) that would consist from the same number of columns with the same headers, only each cell in the row unfolded in a column.

```
   AAA    BBB    CCC 
a  1,2,3  1,2,3  1,2,3
b  2,3,4  2,3,4  2,3,4
```

if I click somewhere that says "a" it makes a new table:

```
   AAA   BBB  CCC 
1. 1     1    1
2. 2     2    2
3. 3     3    3
```

and so on.
Should I read a row into an array, then for each value in the array parse it into another array separating by commas, then construct a 2D array out of this, then manually construct each row and add rows one by one... Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It is safe to assume that each original column value will have the same number of values when unfolded?

Comment: I thought it was, however, just found out that some legacy entries in my DB may have different number of values. Anyways, thanks a lot, it gave me an idea on how to approach it.

Comment: I added a test for columns that are short.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method, testing for varying column sizes:

```
public static class DataTableExt {
    public static DataTable UnfoldRow(this DataRow src) {
        var ans = src.Table.Clone();
        var work = src.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => src.Field<string>(c.ColumnName).Split(',')).ToList();
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < work[0].Length; ++j1)
            ans.Rows.Add(work.Select(w => j1 < w.Length ? w[j1] : "").ToArray());

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Then you extract the `DataRow` as you would like, and pass it:

```
var unfoldedRow = dt.Rows[0].UnfoldRow();
```

Comment: I'm getting the following two errors:

Error CS1106 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class 
Error CS1061 'DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnNames' and no accessible extension method 'ColumnNames' accepting a first argument of type 'DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm sorry, the code was setup to use the obvious extension `ColumnNames()` - I have modified it to not need the extension. You should probably read up on how to use extension methods - they must be defined in a `static` `class`, hence the `public static class DataTableExt`.